Tuya plugin delivers error code 2427 when i start Homebridge
When i start Homebridge, the Tuya plugin gives this error:
[Tuya] Login failed. code=2427, msg=the user did not scan the code to bind the cloud project

If it is related to the qr code that links the devices registered in the tuya app, then i already did that and i don't know why it would give me that error.
Otherwise i don't know what it is related to.
I tried looking for some videos on youtube and some guides on the official tuya developer platform but nothing seems to be the solution for my problem.

Make sure you enter the Tuya Smart App login details in the plugin and not Tuya IoT platform login. This was a mistake I did when I was setting up this plugin.

worked for me. thanks
